# OSX swift no module named six

Tags: python, swift

When I open my terminal and type in "swift", following Import error occurs

```
Air-zyx:~ zhangyongxu$ swift
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Resources/Python/lldb/__init__.py", line 98, in <module>
import six
ImportError: No module named six
```

and here is my python version.

```
Air-zyx:~ zhangyongxu$ python --version
Python 3.6.4 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

I have already downloaded the "six" module, but it is still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run it like this: `PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH swift` so that the proper system Python is picked up.

Comment: After I update the system, this problem fixed automatically 